# React Native Starting Problem With Login System

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

[image]

Hi Guys!

I just need some help with the login system. When anyone logged in, I keep information in my storage(`EncryptedStorage`). When I turned off the application and turn on again I get information from Storage. If any information about the user is, the router is going to the Home page directly. But when the app is starting, it visits Login Page and after that opens Home Page(you can see the image below).

I have already checked react-navigation and redux-toolkit AuthFlow, but I haven't found the solution yet. If the app work, I can do login and logout with the changing state(redux). It works, but when the app is starting the first time, the result is like the below image. Maybe there is a solution in there but I didn't understand.

Please give me the best solution and clarify.

Thanks...

Comment: add the isLoading state to handle this behaviour so login screen will not appear if loggedIn

Answer (score 0):

It will be necessary to review your control mechanism. It is possible to experience such problems when you have it checked according to the first value. In the first case, if it is null or undefined, it will return null, otherwise the actual function will start to run. You can use the sample code below:

```
const myStore = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

return myStore.UserId != null ? (
    myStore.UserId.length > 0 ? (
      <HomeRouter />
    ) : (
      <LoginRouter />
    )
  ) : null;
```